# Google Drive Android GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

When the exception **GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException** is thrown I use

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(exception.getConnectionStatusCode())
```

to generate and show the Dialog.
The generated Dialog shows:

Title-> "Update Google Play Services"
This app won't run unless you update Google Play services.

Google Drive is only a part of my App, so the message is confusing.

My proposal is to change the text to a universal text that could be usable in many scenarios. For example: 
"This App has functions which depend on Google Play Services. If you do not update it, this functions won't work"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, so create your own error dialog to say whatever you want. The method is available to make it easier to provide this functionality.

Comment: I was using the google play services.jar. By using the project lib version I now have access to the strings used by the dialog and can change them. Furthermore I added buttons to the dialog returned by GooglePlayServicesUtil.